# Can a dropdown in-email, like from G+, be implemented without special support from the email client?

Tags: email, javascript, google+

Noticed today this great trinket from Google: in their notification emails upon new G+ followers, the recipient can add someone to a circle directly from a dropdown in the email.  (See below).

The HTML for the page clearly shows the related `div` has been attached to the end of the body, suggesting that the div di not 'ship with' the email and then was displayed via in-email javascript.

Is this kind of interactivity available to any engineer / product developer?  Is this only something that Google gets to do because they control Gmail services?

---

[image]

Comment: This looks like a developer question, do you have any UX related questions regarding this interaction?

Comment: I think it's a technology question, regarding what interactions are possible in email.  Should I reframe in the general: **"What kinds of javascript-interactivity mechanisms are possible in emails?"**

Comment: That is also quite open ended, the specific your question is, the better the probability of getting a good answer. You might ask, "How is this out of the blue drop down compared to a traditional drop down?" or something similar.

Comment: @rk I could change the question around heavily away from the tech of UX, but at that rate I should perhaps delete and open another?

Comment: That would be wise :)

Answer (score 1):

Not doable... Virtually every email client strips javascript out of emails. I assume web based email clients do as well.

The feature you are seing is probably a part of the gmail app and not the email itself.

Comment: I did some determination and it looks doable.  Since this question is being voted closed for topic, my details would probably be inappropriate to this forum.  Thanks, though